# How to split string on spaces but allow escaped non-split regions? (Python)

Tags: python, split

If I have a string:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I can execute:

```
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split(' ')
    => ['The','quick','brown','fox','jumps','over','the','lazy','dog.']
```

But now, let's assume I have a string like this:

```
'The [quick brown fox] jumps over the [lazy dog.]'
```

I want this result:

```
['The','[quick brown fox]','jumps','over','the','[lazy dog.]']
```

Splitting on the `' '` character will obviously yield:

```
['The','[quick','brown','fox]','jumps','over','the','[lazy','dog.]']
```

Another example, that we might often see in CSV parsing:

```
'The,[quick,brown,fox],jumps,over,the,[lazy,dog.]'.somehow_split_with_delimiters()
    => ['The','[quick brown fox]','jumps','over','the','[lazy dog.]']
```

Summary: I want to split a string, but I want to allow for a delimiter that, when used, *skips* splitting the string on split delimiters found within the "escape" delimiter.

The only solution I have for this now is parsing the string char by char and building the list:

```
delimiter = ','
final_parts = []
temp_string = ''
in_escape = False
for ch in myString:
    if (ch == '['):
        in_escape = True
    if (ch == ',' and in_escape = False):
        final_parts.append(temp_string)
        temp_string=''
    else:
        temp_string += ch
    if (ch == ']'):
        in_escape = False
return final_parts
```

or first splitting the list then iterating it looking for delimiters to combine the results:

```
initial_parts = 'The [quick brown fox] jumps over the [lazy dog.]'.split(' ')
final_parts = []
temp_part = ''
in_escape = False
for part in initial_parts:
    if (part[0] == '['):
        in_escape = True
    if (in_escape = True):
        temp_part += part + ' '
    else:
        final_parts.append(part)            
    if (part[-1] == ']'):
        in_escape = False
        final_parts.append(temp_part.strip(' '))
return final_parts
```

Both of these methods seem extremely clunky and error-prone (And I probably have many bugs in there anyway as I wrote them quickly.) They also don't account for possible escaping of the escape delimiter itself (e.g. they won't account for `\[` or `\]` to indicate that the character is *not* signifying the start of an escaped parameter)

It feels like there should be a simpler way to do string splitting while allowing escape characters. Shells for example do this all the time; `cp my file.txt my new file.txt` will result in extraneous parameters, but escaping with `cp "my file.txt" "my new file.txt"` works.

Comment: You haven't given enough of the requirements you expect to have respected. How do you expect these to be handled? `[[`, `]]`, `[ [`, `] ]`, `[ ]`, etc. And how does the example you give for the shell command relate in any meaningful way to the rest of your question? I see you started to realise the escaping issue with your latest edit. I suggest with some more thinking you will start to better understand the full complexity of your question.

Comment: I assume shells parse parameters in some way and handle escaped sequences. I was stating that I'm looking for a similar function.

Comment: For now, we can safely assume the delimiters themselves (`[` and `]`) will never appear in the tokens. If that ever is a need, I could probably work from that point to implement a way to properly handle the escaped delimiters. If the string `[[This is a string]]` appears, it should become one token, as is. If `[ ]` is found, it should be added as a token of three chars. A closing `]` can always be assumed to be the end of an escaped token Extra `]`'s can be ignored and treated as normal chars. In fact, the `]` will always be at the end of a token.

Comment: I seriously suggest you go and think a lot more deeply about this and give us the requirements you have for this specific task. As I am sure you are starting to realise a general answer is very very very hard. Specify exactly what you do and do not want to have this new function achieve and it can be written but it will be fragile and case specific.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use regular expression. I have to handle two cases: a single word `(\w+)`, or a square bracket group of words `(\[[^\]]\])`.

```
s = 'The [quick brown fox] jumps over the [lazy dog.]'

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)|(\[[^\]]+\])')

pattern.findall(s)
Out[32]: 
[('The', ''),
 ('', '[quick brown fox]'),
 ('jumps', ''),
 ('over', ''),
 ('the', ''),
 ('', '[lazy dog.]')]

[a or b for a, b in pattern.findall(s)]
Out[33]: ['The', '[quick brown fox]', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '[lazy dog.]']
```

Notice in the `Out[32]` result, we got a list of either the first pattern or the second. One way to go from this list of tuples to list of strings is shown in the next line using the `or` trick: the expression `a or b` will return the non-empty string of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something that started with a regex split on `[]` first, then process the sub parts.  Along these lines:

```
>>> s = 'The [quick brown fox] jumps over the [lazy dog.]'
>>> def bracket_split(delim, string):
...   initial = re.split('[\[\]]', string)
...   result = []
...   for s in initial:
...     if not s: continue # throw away blank strings
...     if s.startswith(delim) or s.endswith(delim):
...       result.extend(s.strip(delim).split(delim))
...     else:
...       result.append(s.join('[]'))
...   return result
... 
>>> 
>>> bracket_split(' ', s)
['The', '[quick brown fox]', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '[lazy dog.]']
```

But I'll be the first to admit that it's fragile.  `'[ this would break ]` it because the delimiter is within the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches either a square bracket pair including any contained characters, or a sequence of non whitespace characters. The pattern would be:

`\[.*?\]|\S+`

Use it like this:

```
>>> pattern = r'\[.*?\]|\S+'
>>> s = 'The [quick brown fox] jumps over the [lazy dog.]'
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\]|\S+', s)
['The', '[quick brown fox]', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '[lazy dog.]']
```

This is a rather simplistic approach that ignores possibilities such as nested square brackets. The order of alternatives in the pattern is significant in that the bracket match is attempted first.

You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/ZizX3q/1

For the CSV example you would change the pattern to:

`\[.*?\]|[^,]+`

to match the contents of paired brackets or any sequence of non-delimeter characters, in this case a comma:

```
>>> pattern = r'\[.*?\]|[^,]+'
>>> s = 'The,[quick,brown,fox],jumps,over,the,[lazy,dog.]'
>>> re.findall(pattern, s)
['The', '[quick,brown,fox]', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '[lazy,dog.]']
```

BTW I think that your expected output for the CSV example is wrong: it has removed the commas within the brackets, e.g. '[quick brown fox]', but I think that the commas should remain.